# Could not evaluate expression: Activator.CreateInstance<T>()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, generics, activator

I'm using Activator.CreateInstace() to create a generic instance. But when I use this to create a instance of an object:

```
public class SelectStageSaveData
{
    public string GlobalPartnershipPoints { get; set; }
}
```

I get the message "Could not evaluate expression" when I'm debugging the code and trying to see GlobalPartnershipPoints. I've thought the value for this string were "empty" in this case, but I can't get any value. Does anyone know what is happening? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Code where I create the instace:

```
  if (!isolatedStorage.FileExists(file))
  {
        this.SaveData<T>((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)), file);
  }
```

or

```
  if (!isolatedStorage.FileExists(file))
  {
        this.SaveData<T>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>(), file);
  }
```

I get the same result with both.

Comment: Can we see the code where you call CreateInstance()?

Comment: Could you show the instantiating code?

Comment: How are you trying to see it? Stepping into SaveData and using a QuickWatch or mouseover?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson watch and mouseover.

Comment: Where are you actually placing the breakpoint, inside SaveData()? What do you get if you set the result of CreateInstance() into a variable and then inspect it on the line after?

Comment: I've put the breakpoint in "this.SaveData..." line. I get the same with the variable. :/

Comment: Post the full debugger message, it is usually followed by **because blah-blah**

Comment: Also with the code you have shown you don't really need `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` - just add a new constraint and do `new T()`

Comment: @HansPassant only "Could not evaluate expression".

Comment: @BrokenGlass doens't work, it generates a compilation error.

Comment: Please post the full generic class - did you add the `new` constraint?

Comment: "Could not evaluate expression" is a debugger message, not a compiler error or an exception. Since you see a debugger message, I assume that Visual Studio breaks on an exception. Post the full exception message, stack trace and relevant code.

Comment: @dtb I was referring to the debugger message, and not compiler or exception.

Comment: @Leila what is the compilation error when you try to use `new` instead?  It could very well be the reason that `CreateInstance` isn't working in the first place.

Comment: @TimS. Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint

Comment: Thanks to everybody, but I think there's no solution for this problem. Probably is a problem in visual studio debug visualization, and it doesn't work well at all.

Comment: @TimS. I've added and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

> I've thought the value for this string were "empty" in this case

Until you initialize the property, the value will be `null` by default. If you use a private field :

```
public class SelectStageSaveData
{
    private string _GlobalPartnershipPoints = "";
    public string GlobalPartnershipPoints 
    { 
      get { return _GlobalPartnershipPoints;} 
      set { _GlobalPartnershipPoints = value; }
     }
}
```

Then you should get "" as default.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I've made a mistake. The expected value is null. But What I can't understand is why I get the "could not evaluate" message, and not the null value.

Comment: An alternate way to set this default value, which may or may not be preferable to the above, is to define the default `SelectStageSaveData` constructor to set the property to `""`.